# Microsoft PowerToys install PowerRename only

Tags: powertoys

Is it possible to install PowerRename from the the Microsoft PowerToys without all the other software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PowerToys is a suite of tools.

However, Microsoft state that (emphasis my own)

> PowerRename enables you to perform bulk renaming, searching and replacing file names. It includes advanced features, such as using regular expressions, targeting specific file types, previewing expected results, and the ability to undo changes. **This code is based on Chris Davis's SmartRename.**

So you could use the [authors tool](https://github.com/chrdavis/SmartRename), in-place of PowerRename if you didn't want the full suite of tools.